# Consume SOAP webservice using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, web-services, soap

I have a SOAP web service in Java which needs to be called from an HTML page using jQuery. Can somebody tell me how to do that? I am new to it.

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search reveals that there is a jquery plugin for this:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient

Download, examples and further information available from this link.

Comment: can you please ell me from where to download the example. i am unable to find in the url mentioned above

Comment: Annoyingly, you're right -- the links on that page seem to all be broken. Grr. Not even a functional download link. I should have checked that before posting. This link might help you - it looks like it contains the original source code (plus a bit extra on top): http://plugins.jquery.com/files/jquery.soapRequest.js.txt

Comment: jquery.com has changed their URLs. Now the project link is:  [http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/](http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/).  +1 for the only solution here that actually works.

Answer (score 3):

there is a relatively new plugin available:

http://plugins.jquery.com/soap/

I forked the project, and have been working on some modifications (the plugin did not handle the service I was working with). I hope to get my updates merged at some point, but would be happy to have any feedback.

https://github.com/zachofalltrades/jquery.soap

Answer (score 0):

ya you can do it by this way as bellow.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:button').addClass("btnClass");
    fillData();
    $('#btnGet').click(function() {
        fillData();
    });
    function fillData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "../myService.asmx/getStudent",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                //var nMsg = (typeof msg.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + msg.d + ')') : msg.d;
                var t = "<table width='80%' id='resTab'> <tr>" +
                      "<td colspan='5' style='text-align:center'><font size='3'><strong>Your Search Result......</strong></font></td></tr> <tr><td style='text-align:left' colspan='5'><hr></td></tr> "
                      + " <tr><td style='text-align:center'>Student ID</td><td style='text-align:center'>Student Name</td><td style='text-align:center'>Student Course</td><td style='text-align:center'>Student USN</td></tr>"
                      + " <tr><td style='text-align:left' colspan='5'><hr><br></td></tr> ";
                $.each(msg.d, function(index, item) {
                t = t + " <tr><td style='text-align:center'>" + item.studId + "</td><td style='text-align:center'>" + item.studName + "</td><td style='text-align:center'>" + item.studCourse + "</td><td style='text-align:center'>" + item.studUsn + "</td><td><input type='button' ID='btn-" + item.studId + "' value='Delete' class='new-button' />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type='button' ID='upd-" + item.studId + "' value='Update' class='upd-button' /></td></tr>";
                    t = t + " <tr><td style='text-align:left' colspan='5'><hr></td></tr> ";
                });
                t = t + " </table> ";
                $("#stdData").html(t);
            },
            error: function(msg) { }
        });
    }
```

Here I am showing the data into a div ............

so Reply me if it solved and if any query ping me.

Comment: +1 for NOT formatting your code - at least make the OP work a little for 'plz send teh codez'  (BTW, I have no idea if this even works, but the upvote still seems warranted)

Comment: I guess this is a request to REST web service. fo rme i have a java SOAP webservice.

Comment: Uhh... no.  This isn't a SOAP request, it's a JSON request.  If you wire this code to a SOAP service, it will fail.  -1

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is the link You can go through this for more simple usage.

http://www.andrewrowland.com/article/display/consume-dot-net-web-service-with-jquery

Make this answer if it solves ur problem.

Thank You

Comment: This is a link that goes to code that services JSON requests.  It's not useful and doesn't answer the question.