# Consume WCF Service with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wcf

I have a simple WCF service that looks like this;

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPostService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string CheckAlive();
```

and...

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class PostService : IPostService
{
    public string CheckAlive()
    {
        return "I'm here.";
    }
```

In my MVC Web Project I have a Service Reference to my webservice.

I then have jQuery code like this...

```
    function callWebMethod() {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/MyWebService/Service1/mex/CheckAlive",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (msg) {
                alert("data:" + msg.d);
            }, error: function(a,b,c){ alert("error:" + b + ":" + c); }
        });
    }
```

However I always get a "Bad Request" error.  I've never consumed a webservice with jQuery before and am floundering at this point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [consume SOAP webservice using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787309/consume-soap-webservice-using-jquery)

Comment: possibly but i don't have an asmx file nor can i have one

Comment: You put content type `application/soap+xml`, that's why I thought you had one - anyway, if you just want to read XML back from the endpoint with Ajax, see here: http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/

Comment: do you have a `svc` file? also the url seems incorrect, i think the parameter less method is called by default, how you have defined your routes?

Comment: i dont think you need the contentType in your ajax since your not doing a POST

Answer (score 1):

Hey you have to check your endpoint configuration for WCF service. You can see this post for detailed information - 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery

Answer (score 0):

your `postservice` class has to be decorated with the `[ServiceContract]`

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    [ServiceContract]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class PostService : IPostService
    {
        public string CheckAlive()
        {
            return "I'm here.";
        }
    }
}
```

also have you defined the routes in the Global.ascx file

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

      RouteTable.Routes.MapServiceRoute<MyNamespace.PostService >("Service/SomeName");
    }
```

you can access the service like

```
      url:'http://loalhost:1234/Service/SomeName',
```

Comment: My interface is decorated with [ServiceContract] and if i decorate the class with the same the service won't start.

Comment: in that case you might have to decorate the interface members with the `[OperationContract]` also the implementation also have to have `[OperationContract]`

Comment: Each method is decorated with [OperationContract] in the interface. It's in the code in the question.  Or do you mean to take the decorators out of the interface and into the class?

Comment: can you try removing the `[ServiceContract]` from the interface and just place it on the class that is inheriting the interface also remove the `[OperationContract]` from the interface members